# UUID field within Go Pact consumer test

Tags: go, pact

I'm currently looking at adding Pact testing into my Go code, and i'm getting stuck on how to deal with field types of UUID.
I have the following struct, which I use to deserialise a response from an API to

```
import (
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

type Foo struct {
    ID          uuid.UUID `json:"id"`
    Name        string    `json:"name"`
    Description string    `json:"description"`
}
```

Now, when I try and write my consumer test, it looks something like this

```
    pact.
        AddInteraction().
        Given("A result exists").
        UponReceiving("A request to get all results").
        WithRequest(dsl.Request{
            Method:  "get",
            Path:    dsl.String("/v1"),
        }).
        WillRespondWith(dsl.Response{
            Status:  200,
            Headers: dsl.MapMatcher{"Content-Type": dsl.String("application/json")},
            Body:    dsl.Match(&Foo{}),
        })
```

The problem now, is the mocked response comes through as below, where it tries to put an array of bytes in the "id" field, I'm assuming since behind the scenes that is what the google/uuid library stores it as.

```
{
    "id": [
        1
    ],
    "name": "string",
    "description": "string"
}
```

Has anyone encountered this? And what would be the best way forward - the only solution I can see is changing my model to be a string, and then manually convert to a UUID within my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently can't use the `Match` function this way, as it recurses non primitive structures, albeit it should be possible to override this behaviour with struct tags. Could you please raise a feature request?

The simplest approach is to not use the `Match` method, and just manually express the contract details in the usual way.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! For anyone else following along - feature request raised here https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-go/issues/179

Answer (score 0):

The internal representation of uuid.UUID is `type UUID [16]byte` but json representation of UUID is string

```
var u uuid.UUID
u, _ = uuid.Parse("f47ac10b-58cc-0372-8567-0e02b2c3d479")

foo1 := Foo{u, "n", "d"}
res, _ := json.Marshal(foo1)

fmt.Println(string(res))
```

```
{
  "id": "f47ac10b-58cc-0372-8567-0e02b2c3d479",
  "name": "n",
  "description": "d"
}
```

and then load marshaled []byte

```
var foo Foo

json.Unmarshal(res, &foo)
```